# Python - Syntax error on colon in list

Tags: python, list, syntax

I've been trying to create a simple dictionary to define a word that the user inputs. After defining the dictionary and it's words, I'm trying to print the definition of the input'd word. For some reason, when I try to run this program there is a syntax error on the colon in the list. I'm not sure how to fix this problem, I am aware that there are easier ways to do this but I'm trying to practice using lists.
Here is the code so far:

## dictionary

```
dic1 = [
    'bug':'A broken piece of code that causes a program to stop functioning'
    'string':'A piece of text'
    'integer':'A whole number'
    'float':'A decimal number'
    'function':'A block of organized and clean code that performs a task/action'
    'syntax':'A set of rules that says how a program will be coded'      
    ]

q = input("What coding related word do you want defined?")
if q in dic1:
    print(dic1[q])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot a comma at the end of each entry in the dict. Dicts use curly braces "`{...}`"

```
dic1 = {
    'bug':'A broken piece of code that causes a program to stop functioning',
    'string':'A piece of text',
    'integer':'A whole number',
    'float':'A decimal number',
    'function':'A block of organized and clean code that performs a task/action',
    'syntax':'A set of rules that says how a program will be coded',      
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou! :D I knew it would be something simple that I was missing