# Python string array without delimiter becomes one single entry

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm wondering why the following python array is valid (notice the missing comma between 'foo' and 'bar':

`a = ['hello', 'world', 'foo' 'bar']`

Printing 'a' outputs the following:

`['hello', 'world', 'foobar']`

Why is it even allowed, to omit a comma, if there is at least one comma? I thought there'd be an error like

*You started the array with comma delimited strings, why on earth are you now, all of a sudden, omitting commas? Are you sure that's not mistake?*

Comment: When you print `a` it should be `['hello', 'world', 'foobar']` not `['hello', 'worldfoobar']`

Comment: I get `['hello', 'world', 'foobar']` (python 3) . What version of python are you using?

Comment: This is by design, Python concatenates adjacent string literals. [*"This feature can be used to reduce the number of backslashes needed, to split long strings conveniently across long lines, or even to add comments to parts of strings..."*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540634/issue-warning-for-missing-comma-between-list-items-bug for other ways to check for this

Comment: I edited, of course it's ```['hello', 'world', 'foobar']```